# How to allow unsafe content in angular reactive formcontrol (avoid WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content)

Tags: angular

I am using an editor control (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kolkov/angular-editor), which is set up in the HTML like this, using Angular 7, reactive forms:

```
<angular-editor formControlName="labelContent" [config]="editorConfig"></angular-editor>
```

The tool sometimes creates HTML markup that Angular views as unsafe. Specifically, when I set the background of some text to be some color, the tool implements it like this:

`<span style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);">Green Background</span>`

When this happens, the style information is stripped away from the value of the labelContent form control, and I see a message in the console saying: "WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content". Consequently, I can't save the highlighted background to my database, so I can't later display it.

How can I allow this content to be submitted? I'm familiar with *displaying* unsafe content using things like sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml, but how do I incorporate something like that to allow the *user* (via the tool) to submit markup which Angular views as unsafe? Can I somehow configure the formcontrol to allow this?

Comment: for a project that size you're prob better off asking on their github

Comment: What makes you think this is a large project? Just curious.

Comment: I don't, I think it's a small to mid project. Large projects generally don't respond to usage questions on their github as they're known enough to find answers on SO. But smaller - mid size projects usually will respond to usage issues as you're less likely to find people on SO who will know the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that sanitization could be bypassed using configuration settings for the editing tool. Easy fix once discovered.

Answer (score 1):

use in Config

```
sanitize: true
```

This Component Automatically Get Sanitized Value.